# In 3D, find coefficients of linear interpolation of 3 vertices of a triangle, given a point on the triangle

Tags: linear-algebra

In 3D, I have a point $P$ on a triangle, I know that $P$ can be represented as a linear combination of the three vertices of the triangle. Thus, how can I calculate these coefficients?

Currently, I wrote them in matrix form (below) and try to inverse the matrix that holds the three vertices, but it fails due to matrix singularity.
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
P_1 \\
P_2 \\
P_3 
\end{matrix}
 =
\begin{matrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
z_1 & z_2 & z_3 \\
\end{matrix} ^{-1}
*
\begin{matrix}
\alpha_1 \\
\alpha_2 \\
\alpha_3 
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Give the matrix atleast?

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh the matrix is just a 3 by 3 matrix. Do you need the value?

Comment: If you’d like for someone to show you where you might’ve gone wrong, it would be rather helpful to show your work. We’re not all mind-readers here.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Conversion_between_barycentric_and_Cartesian_coordinates.

Comment: @amd The link that you provide helps me. But in 3D, the matrix $T$ becomes a non-square matrix, right? Thus, it's not invertible. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh Added the matrix.

Comment: @amd Added the matrix.